# CSS Selectors with commas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using JQuery Bootgrid for the tables in my project.

I am having trouble targeting a specific class on a specific element. I can't change the class or apply my own class because the class is created by Bootgrid for the table.

I am trying to make the select boxes hidden in #table1, but not hidden in #table2.  I am trying to do this by setting different width values on the associated classes.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo5g0g3/) to show the problem better. You can find the CSS I am having trouble with at the very bottom of the CSS section.

```js
// This works:
#table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}

// But it breaks this:
#table2 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 3%;
}


// This doesn't work, but I thought it should:
#table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}
#table1 .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}
#table2 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell {
    width: 3%;
}
#table2 .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 3%;
}


// This also doesn't work, but I thought it should:
#table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, #table1 .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}
```

I thought I understood how commas work in CSS, but maybe not?  Breaking the selectors into 2 lines does not apply the styling like I thought it would. How do I target both classes in #table1 with one line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo5g0g3/) to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: As @Paulie_D mentioned, the code must be in the question itself. Yours in on JSFiddle, not here on Stack Overflow. You have a Stack Snippet, which is great, but it doesn't include the HTML, which means the CSS doesn't do anything, which is bad.

Comment: ...and the demo should be **minimal**, your fiddle is WAAAAY to much.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what is `select-cell`?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I can't figure out how to include bootgrid in a Stack Snippet. Is it possible?

Comment: @Paulie_D That is basically the minimum needed to get a Bootgrid running in JSFiddle that can illustrate my problem.  All that would need adjusting is the last few lines in the CSS section...

Comment: @Tibrogargan select-cell is the checkbox column on the left most side of the Bootgrid table.

Comment: @bicycle_guy don't see that in your html.  Is that supplied by bootgrid? (you should update your tags to include that BTW).  Because on the face of it, your selectors don't work because they don't match any HTML

Comment: You may just need to remove the space between `#table1` and `.bootgrid-table`, or simply remove `.bootgrid-table`. These two selectors are on the same element.

Comment: @Tibrogargan check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo5g0g3/) I made to show the problem.

Comment: @Alex.S removing .bootgrid-table after the comma resolved the problem. Thank you! Repost as an answer so I can give you credit if you want.

Comment: @bicycle_guy You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put #table1 before BOTH of your selectors, including the one after the comma because it doesn't carry over.

Currently you have

```
#table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}
```

You need to change

```
.bootgrid-table th.select-cell
```

to

```
#table1 .bootgrid-table th.select-cell
```

The comma resets all the selectors so you need to write the selector after the comma as if you're starting from scratch.

Comment: I tried this earlier and it didn't work:

        #table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, #table1 .bootgrid-table th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}

Comment: @bicycle_guy well then like the comment on the main post said...you need to post more details.

Comment: I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo5g0g3/) to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the problem:

```css
// Solution:
#table1 .bootgrid-table td.select-cell, #table1 th.select-cell {
    width: 1%;
}
```